# how to use amp-script to submit a form and get data from server every X seconds

Tags: amp-html

I've been reading about [amp-script](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) and I know it's in experimental mode right now. However there're few things I've been trying without any success and would like to hear from you if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do.

Basically would like to use **amp-script** to submit a form every X seconds, in order to get (action=GET) data from our servers every X seconds.

I've been trying this with success

```
window.setInterval( () => {
   console.log('test!');
}, 3000 );
```

Now I'd like to do the form submission like this:

```
window.setInterval( () => {
   document.getElementyById('my-form').submit();
}, 3000 );
```

According to this: https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/master/web_compat_table.md, HTMLFormElement.submit() is not yet supported.

My questions are:

1. any ETA on when this will be supported ?
2. Can we use amp-script for AMP4Emails event being on Experimental mode ?
3. any other ideas on how to accomplish form submission to get some data from our server every X seconds ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- re 1.: please [file a feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/issues/new) on Github for this.
- re 2.: AMP4Email doesn't support amp-script and I'm not aware of any plans for it to be supported in the future.
- re 3.: You could read the form data in your amp-script and periodically get the data via the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Sidenote: have you tried using the amp-live-list component? It supports periodically fetching new data out of the box (without form support though).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Already filled feature request for this and will do the same for supporting amp-script for AMP4Email as well.

About 3rd, will try doing something like that. Thanks in advance!